Tried to connect Mend.io to my Azure instance through Organization Settings > Azure Active Directory, and now I can't access my Azure subscription
I want to connect Mend.io to my azure instance. I was told it needed to connect to my Azure Default Directory so I messed with some settings and broke my access to my subscription.
In Azure I'm getting this and similar notifications whenever I try to do anything:
"The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.
Additional information from the call to get a token:
Extension: Microsoft_Azure_Support
Resource: self
Details: The logged in user is not authorized to fetch tokens for extension 'Microsoft_Azure_Support' because the user account is not a member of tenant 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
Error details: invalid_grant: 50020 - [2024-06-03 19:31:16Z]: AADSTS50020: User account '{EUII Hidden}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Azure Portal) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."
This is all to say I can't access my subscription anymore and I'm not sure where to go from here. If anyone has a starting point or has experienced anything like this I'd greatly appreciate the help.
I was trying to connect the Mend.io extension for Azure DevOps to my Azure instance. I navigated to my Azure directories and user settings and changed a couple things while trying to connect. It seemed like it worked as an option came up to connect in DevOps. I clicked it, got a warning about possible tenant issues, thought it would be fine, and selected it.
Shockingly, I'm having tenant issues. Back in my Azure instance, I can no longer access my subscription. It's like I lost access to the default directory it was stored in. In DevOps Mend.io still isn't connected, but I can deploy to that Azure subscription, so it's still out there somewhere, I just can't access it.
I've been using the same account for both Azure and Azure DevOps, but now in Azure it's acting like I don't have a subscription at all. There's an option to get a new free subscription, but I can't access mine. I still have the email in my inbox that confirms I have that subscription, but when I click on the link it just takes me to the same, subscriptionless, home page.

Based on your description, you are attempting to use this Mend Bolt (formerly WhiteSource) extension within Azure DevOps. Since your organization is not linked to an Azure Active Directory, the extension displayed a warning stating, "Please connect your organization to an Azure AD via Organization Settings > Azure Active Directory."
The problem is that, after you connected your organization to Microsoft Entra ID( Azure Active Directory ), you can't access your Azure subscription in Azure Portal.
The subscription should not disappear after this action. In this case, you can check the Directories + subscriptions in https://portal.azure.com/#settings/directory. To prevent the previous account's cache from affecting the login, please use an InPrivate window or clear your browser's cache before logging in.
If you can't find the subscription, switch to another directory and check if the subscription is there. For example:

Before switch Directories:


After switch Directories:



Regarding the error ID AADSTS50020, you may refer to this troubleshooting document: Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant for more details.
Update：
You can use the az account tenant list to check if there are more than one tenant exist.
Then you can use az account subscription list to check if there is any subscription under the tenant.
If you still can't find the subscription, it is recommended to create a support ticket to better check the issue in the backend.

Still experiencing issues, there are no other directories in my Azure portal, nor are there any subscriptions.
Using az account set --subscription  I get the following error: The subscription of '1bba84fc-1b84-427e-858b-68ff050cdad9' doesn't exist in cloud 'AzureCloud'.
The troubleshooting I've found online hasn't worked,, and even after logging out and logging back in, when I try to list accounts or subscriptions I'm asked to run az login again.
In Users under Default directory, there's one user xxxx_gmail.com#EXT#@xxxxxxgmail040.onmicrosoft.com

Additionally, I can switch directories in DevOps. I can switch between Default Directory and Microsoft Account. I've been using the Microsoft Account Directory for everything, so all of my deployments are on that directory in Azure. But now, I'm unable to access that directory in Azure somehow, all I can see is the Default Directory where I don't have a subscription loaded.

Hi @CameronCox, you can use the az account tenant list to check if there are more than one tenant exist. Then you can use az account subscription list to check if there is any subscription under the tenant. If you still can't find the subscription, it is recommended to create a support ticket to better check the issue in the backend.
